# Which parts of the Townshend Act were repealed in 1770?

Tags: united-states, british-empire, 18th-century, taxes

The [Townshend Acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Townshend_Act) were passed in 1767 and partially repealed in 1770. Which clauses were repealed at that time?

I've looked around and found the original text, but I cannot find specifically what parts were repealed in 1770 and which parts stayed in act.

Comment: Where did you disappear @Luke? I remember us being head to head in terms of rep, and then you vanished. The site is not as much fun without some friendly competition ;)

Comment: @YannisRizos Moderating GFH. I'll catch up one of these days...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer is "everything except for the tax on tea".

> [The Townshend Acts except for the taxes on tea were finally repealed in March of 1770.](http://www.hobart.k12.in.us/cside/American%20Revolution/revwar/townshen.htm)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Townshend_Act#Partial_repeal) confirms

> On the 5 of March 1770— the same day as the Boston Massacre—Lord North, the new Prime Minister, presented a motion in the House of Commons that called for partial repeal of the Townshend Revenue Act.[63] Although some in Parliament advocated a complete repeal of the act, North disagreed, arguing that the tea duty should be retained to assert "the right of taxing the Americans".[63] After debate, the Repeal Act[64] received the Royal Assent on 12 April 1770.[65]
>   Historian Robert Chaffin argued that little had actually changed:
>   It would be inaccurate to claim that a major part of the Townshend Acts had been repealed. The revenue-producing tea levy, the American Board of Customs and, most important, the principle of making governors and magistrates independent all remained. In fact, the modification of the Townshend Duties Act was scarcely any change at all.[66]
>   The Townshend duty on tea was retained when the 1773 Tea Act was passed, which allowed the East India Company to ship tea directly to the colonies. The Boston Tea Party soon followed, which set the stage for the American Revolution.

Comment: Have you been able to locate the original text of the Repeal Act?

Comment: "Everything except for the tax on tea." That's my recollection too. And the basis of the 1773 Boston TEA party.